# Flutter: Align two widgets on a single TabBarView page

Tags: flutter

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I cannot work out how to align the widgets on the page of my first tab.

I have three tabs:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const int tabsCount = 3;
    return DefaultTabController(
      initialIndex: 1,
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('TabBar'),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.beach_access_sharp),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.brightness_5_sharp),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Center(child: Widget1()), //this is a full blank page to draw on
            Center(child: Widget2()),
            Center(child: Widget3())
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But I have `Widget4() //a CheckBoxList() I want to expand from top to bottom of the page` that I want to align down the right side of the first tab page.

I tried various version of the below:

```
body: const TabBarView(children: [
          Container(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: Widget4(),
            ),
            child: Widget1(),
          ),
          Widget2(),
          Widget3()
        ]),
```

EDIT:

I am trying to create this (pardon the rudimentary drawing). The body of the `Tab 1` page has a "canvas feature" that a user can create text boxes in. This is Widget1 and is the majority of the page/screen.

Then on the right hand side of the page and extending from bottom to the top of the page is a "Check Box List Widget" that allows a user to add "things to do" and then check them off. Like this:

```
 _______
|       |
| TAB 1 |
|_______|
 _______________________________________________
|                               | This side is |
|                               | a check list |
|                               |              |
|                               |  [] item 1   |
|                               |  [] item 2   |
|                               |              |
|  This side is the "canvas"    |              |
|                               |              |
|                               |              |
|                               |              |
|                               |              |
|                               |              |
|                               |              |
|                               |              |
|_______________________________|______________|
```

I would like for both of them to scroll independently.

And I can't work out how to combine Widget1 and Widget4 so they are treated as "one" page when I add them to the body part of `TabBarView` like below:

```
body: const TabBarView(children: [
          (Wiget1 + Widget4),
          Widget2(),
          Widget3()
        ]),
```

I haven't created the canvas Widget1.
`CheckBoxListWidget` is a straight copy from Flutter docs:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CheckBoxList
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class LabeledCheckbox extends StatelessWidget {
  const LabeledCheckbox({
    super.key,
    required this.label,
    required this.padding,
    required this.value,
    required this.onChanged,
  });

  final String label;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final bool value;
  final ValueChanged<bool> onChanged;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        onChanged(!value);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: padding,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: Text(label)),
            Checkbox(
              value: value,
              onChanged: (bool? newValue) {
                onChanged(newValue!);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CheckBoxWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CheckBoxWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<CheckBoxWidget> createState() => _CheckBoxWidgetState();
}

class _CheckBoxWidgetState extends State<CheckBoxWidget> {
  bool _isSelected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LabeledCheckbox(
      label: 'This is the label text',
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      value: _isSelected,
      onChanged: (bool newValue) {
        setState(() {
          _isSelected = newValue;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Do I use a `row` and split the two widgets?
do I use two separate `sized boxes`, `stacked`, `container`??

Comment: The TabBar have nothing to do with your alignment... But can you present an image of how you would like the page to look? I.e. what you refer to being the content of the first tab?

Comment: Also, you probably have to present the code in `Widget4(`) if you'd like to get better help.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I'll update tonight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Row` for your tab 1 page:

```
Row(
  children: [
    // your canvas widget here
    Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      width: 250,
    ),
    Expanded(
      // your checkbox list here
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.pink,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Output should be like:

[image]

Here is working code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(const DemoApp());

class DemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const DemoApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        initialIndex: 1,
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('TabBar'),
            bottom: const TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.beach_access_sharp),
                ),
                Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.brightness_5_sharp),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    width: 250,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.pink,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              //this is a full blank page to draw on
              Center(
                  child: Container(
                color: Colors.black,
              )),
              Center(
                  child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
              )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually just did something similar and it didn't work. The code doesn't compile. I can't work out what is going on. This is the offending section of code that I cant' get to work: `body: const return TabBarView(children: [ Row(...` It causes an error. why?

Comment: Maybe I will post my code to the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: @chuckd833 Please check my updated answer. Just post all my code.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you. thank you. It was the `const` causing the problem. It was part of the Flutter Create App code so I left it in there. What effect does that `const` have?

Comment: "If you never intend to change a variable, use final or const, either instead of var or in addition to a type. A final variable can be set only once; a const variable is a compile-time constant. (Const variables are implicitly final.)"